# What's the cheapest way to know if a path refers to a folder or a file in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I'm working with a shell extension overlay handler, and I'll be passed a path that I know to be valid, but I don't know if it's a folder or a file.  This operation could be called relatively often, so I want to determine whether it's a file or folder as cheaply as possible.  Using c++ (windows specific is fine for my requirements), how can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [`is_directory`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/operations.htm#is_directory) from [Boost's Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)...

```
is_directory( "foo" )
```

Comment: I would avoid linking to boost (or any other popular library) in the form of a DLL if this is for a shell extension because of risks of loading conflicting versions of the same library in the same process.  Microsoft itself used to recommend against writing shell extensions in .NET for the same reasons (though they've found a way to bypass that specific limitation for .NET).

Comment: boost can be statically linked and there is good documentation around how linking is handled and how it can be safely used. Avoiding the use of popular library kinda defeats the purpose of having a library.

Comment: I didn't recommend against using boost or any other library.  I recommended against linking to them *in the form of a DLL*.

Comment: @AndréCaron, That's interesting, can you elaborate a little more on the danger of including boost?  I'm aware of the .Net issue, which is why I ended up writing the handler in c++, but I have included boost for a couple of the operations.

Comment: @GrantH.: basically, the explorer process loads the DLL containing your in-process COM server that implements the shell extension.  In the process, it also loads the rest of the DLLs' dependencies.  If another shell extension uses a conflicting version of Boost and that extension is loaded in the same process, you may get very weird effects that are difficult to reproduce.  By statically linking, library functions are resolved at link time (not runtime).  If a conflicting (binary incompatible) version is loaded as part of another DLL, you'll be sure all your calls are still resolved correctly.

Answer (score 5):

[GetFileAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would provide this information:

```
const DWORD result = GetFileAttributes("C:\\path\\x");

if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == result)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
}
else if (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY == (result & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
{
    std::cout << "Is directory\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Is file\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the [`stat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) variants, and test the `st_mode` bit.

Answer (score 0):

There's the stat() function family for this, which return metadata about a file/directory, including its type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx

Answer (score 0):

f you are OK with using Windows classes, then simply use this

```
Directory::Exists(path)
```

If true, then you have a folder. Similarly use

```
File::Exists(path)
```

if you want to determine if a path is a file or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is also shlwapi's (Shell API) [`PathIsDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).